# The type or namespace 'Mvc' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web'

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I recently installed VS.NET 2012 and moved my ASP.NET MVC 4 project over. However, on building the solution I get hundreds of errors with :

```
The type or namespace 'Mvc' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference)
```

AFAIK ASP.NET MVC 4 is built into VS 2012 and there is nothing that needs to be installed. Any ideas how to get rid of these errors and build the application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include the reference to the assembly `System.Web.Mvc` in you project.

Comment: duh... the references were broken. Thanks :)

Comment: For future solution seekers, this may be in the 'Extensions' section of 'Assemblies' in the Reference Manager dialog of Visual Studio now...

Comment: didn't help, the error is stil there (the build succeeds, but the error aprears in one of the open views...)

Comment: In my case, I did move the whole MVC project to another folder, but I forget to fix the `<hintPath>` references on the `.csproj` file.

Comment: yeah, the hintpath can be crucial for this.